# repopulating form: PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form that submits to a third-party service that runs some validation. On error, it redirects to the same page as the form but appends a query string containing the original form values along with an error message.

Because of this query string, the browser sees it as a "new page" and the form is blank.

I've tried one method using PHP ([see Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/populating-form-contents-from-get-especially-radio-buttons#comment21154_13083)) that boils down to: "grab the GET value for each field, on an individual basis, and then set these as the value on the form." It sort of works, but:

- the radio buttons are tricky to deal with
- I don't have full PHP functionality. I'm in WordPress with a PHP-in-pages plugin that can run certain PHP but is choking on defining a function and then re-using it

What is the recommended method (PHP or JavaScript... and I do have jQuery on the site also) for re-populating this form?

Comment: Why are the raios "tricky"? The inability to define a function is not ideal, but you can get around it by just coding things multiple times. Or upgrade hosts?

Comment: radios are 'tricky' because you have to run surprisingly extensive logic on each of them to determine whether to set "checked" or not. It's not impossible, but it's not the same as just setting the value of the input as the value in the GET. Regarding the PHP it's not about upgrading hosts, but about the PHP function being eval'd. I could make the page template have the form hard-coded (no more PHP issue) but then the CMS functionality is out the window for that particular page (not a huge deal mind you).

Comment: How is it surprisingly extensive? I do this with my forms, wouldn't it just be an `if` statement for each button?

Comment: One person's surprise is another person's de rigeur. ;-) It's all relative and subjective. It's just one if, you are correct: `<?php if(($_GET['someVar']) && $_GET['someVar'] == "no") { echo 'checked'; } ?>` repeated for each radio input element. It just seems so repetitive and anti-DRY.

Comment: @GregPettit unless you are assembling your fields dynamically, it won't be easy to repopulate them dynamically as well using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are dynamically assembling your fields, it won't be easy to dynamically repopulate them using PHP. If you *are*, you can do something like this:

### PHP

```
$fields = [
    'username' => ['type' => 'text', 'value' => $_GET['username']],
    'setting1' => ['type' => 'radio', 'value' => $_GET['radio']]
];
foreach( $fields as $name => $input ) {
    echo "<input type='{$input['type']}' name='{$name}' value='{$input['value']}'>";
}
```

If not, you can use a combination of PHP and JavaScript like this. I'm using jQuery to simplify things.

### PHP and JavaScript

```
$fields = $_GET;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var errors = { ';
foreach( $fields as $name => $value ) {
    echo $name . " : '{$value}',\n";
}
echo '};

$.each(errors, function(name, value) {
    $("input[name="+name+"]").val(value);
});
</script>';
```

This is untested and I know there is at least one bug (extra comma in the errors array) but should be a good starting point. The goal of the second method is to assemble an array using PHP which the JavaScript can then use and execute a loop to assign those values to each input field. But again - the logic for select boxes and radio buttons and so on will be complex. Instead of just assigning `val` you would have to set `checked` properties, etc.

Unfortunately I don't know if there are any libraries or jQuery plugins which already do this.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I didn't use this exact approach, but this is the closest to what ended up 'working'. Rather than repopulating dynamically with PHP, I repopulate in a more static way with PHP (one by one), but then I'm using some JavaScript to identify errored fields and populate an error message into an element.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript because PHP forces an extra load on the server. But validating userinput should be done both clientside (JS) as well as (serverside) PHP

Comment: Server-side validation is a must-have, while client-side is a "nice to have". The form isn't being filled out multiple times on a continual basis, so the load is no big deal. But I don't mind doing the re-populating part as JavaScript. Do you know of any JavaScript samples or jQuery plugins that do this sort of thing already? Don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

This is jquery code to check the radiobutton:

```
     $("form :radio:checked").before("CHECKED"); //selects only checked buttons
```

This is code to prevent the form from submission and repopulate your fields:

```
function prepareEventhandlers() {
document.getElementById("formname").onsubmit = function() {
if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") { // e.g. if no email was given
    document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "it didnt work!";
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
}
};
}


window.onload = function () {
prepareEventhandlers();
}
```

good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code snippet; however, I'm not trying to do client-side validation pre-submit (at this stage). Rather I'm taking the values returned in a query string (ie. the GET parameters) and rebuilding the form.

Comment: So, what do you want to do? If you take the form and let it submit to itself serverside in PHP, it's easy to repopulate from the GET values. Just do a lot of repeating procedural programming if you cannot use functions i think

Comment: I am repopulating the form with the submitted values. I have no choice but to submit to the server-side validation, which will redirect to my form page if there are errors. It shows up blank by default (query string makes it a "new" page, browser doesn't auto-fill)

Comment: "I have no choice but to submit to the server-side validation, which will redirect to my form page if there are errors." 
Don't you have the possibility to change this?

Comment: Nope. Not in control of the 3rd party service. Besides that, I honestly don't mind handing off validation to the 3rd party since server-side validation is a must-have. Doing client-side-only validation is against best practices.